# Simple math always returning 0

Tags: android, math, return, return-value, milliseconds

In my app I have a time in milliseconds (between 0 and 60000) divided by a certain value (In the current example it's 60000) Then, I times that by 100.

However, when printing the answer into the log, it always returns 0.

This is my code:

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(activityDuration, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long timeLeftInMillis) {
            int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
            int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

            String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
            countDownTimerTextView.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

            System.out.println("L: " + timeLeftInMillis); // Returns correctly. Values between 0 and 60000
            System.out.println("Activity Duration: " + activityDuration); // Returns correctly. 60000
            System.out.println("Progress: " + (timeLeftInMillis / activityDuration) * 100); // Returns 0
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeLeftInMillis / activityDuration` is integer division and is always truncated to the nearest integer.

You need to cast to a float or double before doing the divsion i.e.
`((double)timeLeftInMillis / activityDuration) * 100)`

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by user3818491](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309411/5772882) gives you a correct solution. I should like to contribute the modern version. Don’t use primitive numbers for durations, use the `Duration` class of java.time (the modern Java date and time API). This means, first declare `activityDuration` a `Duration`, for example:

```
    final Duration activityDuration = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
```

IMHO this is already much clearer to read as 1 minute than your value of 60000.

```
    Duration timeLeft = Duration.ofMillis(timeLeftInMillis);
    int minutes = (int) timeLeft.toMinutes();
    int seconds = timeLeft.toSecondsPart();

    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    countDownTimerTextView.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

    System.out.println("L: " + timeLeftInMillis); // Returns correctly. Values between 0 and 60000
    System.out.println("Activity Duration: " + activityDuration); // Returns correctly. 60000
    System.out.println("Progress: " + timeLeft.multipliedBy(100).dividedBy(activityDuration));
```

A possible output is:

```
L: 25555
Activity Duration: PT1M
Progress: 42
```

In this case `00:25` was filled into your text view. `PT1M` comes from `Duration.toString` and means 1 minute (it‘s ISO 8601 format, it goes like this, you will learn to read it easily if you need to).

The `Duration.dividedBy(Duration)` method was introduced in Java 9. For earlier Java versions and Android instead use:

```
    System.out.println(
            "Progress: " + timeLeft.multipliedBy(100).toMillis() / activityDuration.toMillis());
```

The result is the same.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android (only not the modest Java 9 additions). It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (API level 26 and above, I am told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages, for example `import org.threeten.bp.Duration;`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Documentation of the `Duration` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.